# (how) can we create semi circle donut chart, with range labels?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, donut-chart

[image]

I want to create this kind of semi circle donut chart.

```
"series": [
    {
        "name": "xxx",
        "y": 4,
        "start": "50%",
        "end": "40%"
    },
    {
        "name": "yyy",
        "y": 10,
        "start": "40%",
        "end": "10%"
    },
    {
        "name": "zzz",
        "y": 9,
        "start": "10%",
        "end": "-15%"
    }
]
```

START and END points dataLables also has to be displayed in the chart like it is in image. Is it possible?

http://jsfiddle.net/hrvp3gj9/

Comment: I'd suggest you look around for some kind of library that has charts like that.

Comment: You can use a [renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.text) to add missing labels.

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://demos.zingchart.com/view/WOORV4F8) is a solution that uses ZingChart. This uses a combination of two chart, a pie chart and a gauge chart.

The half donut is created with the `scale-r > aperture` attribute set to 180 (which makes a half circle) and the `plot > slice` attribute set to 80 (which makes the hole of the donut).

The gauge chart, which is placed directly over the pie chart, has most of its attributes hidden. However, by setting the same aperture and slice values, we can more easily place labels around the chart. Take note of the `scale-r > item > rules` array that is used to make only certain items visible through the use of the `alpha` (transparency) attribute, which is set to 0 in the `scale-r > item` object.

I'm on the ZingChart team, please let me know if you have any questions :)

Comment: thanks for your answer.  I cannot choose other libraries. I must achieve this (if possible) only with highcharts.

Comment: Did you find solution to this? I am looking for something similar and couldnt find